# Loading an iFrame on click with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is there a way to create a non-specific function to show an iFrame on click?

My reasoning is because I have several iFrame's linking to some other pages, and instead of having to require the browser to load all the pages at the start it will load them on request.

This is the way that I was thinking of going about this:

**HTML**

```
<a class="viewFrame">
  <img src="../button.png"/>
</a>

<iFrame class="frame" src="" title="http://linkToiFrame.com"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('viewFrame').on("click", function(){
   $('frame').attr("src", $('frame').attr("title"));
});

/*Will have a function here to remove the attribute
I am unsure as to whether or not I even need to do this, or if I just
hide the iFrame after, this way I don't have to load it multiple times
if the user clicks the link multiple times.*/
$('close').on("click", function(){
  $('frame').attr("src", "");
});
```

I am curious to know whether or not this seems like a practical way of doing it, or if there are any better ways out there.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you make fiddle for that

Comment: @PitaJ for the loading aspect... quote from question : `"My reasoning is because I have several iFrame's linking to some other pages, and instead of having to require the browser to load all the pages at the start it will load them on request."`

Comment: What you're doing seems fine, but a data-attribute for the source seems more appropriate than using the title.

Comment: @adeneo is there any issues with the close? because I will also be hiding the visibility. I guess my concern is more with the browser... if I remove the `src` when the person clicks on it again will it re-load the iFrames `src` or would it still be cached? Should I do a one-time load, otherwise show?

Answer (score 0):

The **`frame`** is the class of iframe so how can it work with just `$('frame')`

you need to write **`$('.frame')`**

```
'.' is used for classes and '#' for id's
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/xFsUB/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question I just figured out a solution for my own problem, maybe it helps anyone.

In PHP I have an array which is variable, so the source of the iframe should be too.
Also I wanted the iframe to be loaded when I click a `<div>` to open a popup, because I had the feeling that the loading of the iframes causes problems.  Some of this might be a little offtopic.
In my `<script>` I have this code now

```
$(".openpopup").click(function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(".openpopup").data('clicked', true);
  $(".openpopup").fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + this.id+".popup").fadeIn('slow');

  // fill iframe src with iframe title
  document.getElementById('trailerID'+this.id).src = document.getElementById('trailerID'+this.id).title;

});
```

and my `iframe` in the popup `div` looks like this:

```
//...
//php and html code to create the $array and the other components of my content 
//...
  <iframe id="trailerID<?php echo $i;?>" width="560" height="315" src="" title="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $array[$i]["trailer_youtube_id"];?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
//more code and <?php $i++; ?>
```

So I change the `iframe` by clicking the openpopup `div` and using the **title** as a cache for the **src**.

---

By the way - to **close** the `div` and to automatically **stop** the `iframe` this code worked for me:

```
$(".close").click(function () {
  $(".openpopup").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".popup").hide();
  $(".openpopup").data('clicked', false);
  $('iframe').each(function(){
       var el_src = $(this).attr("src");
       $(this).attr("src",el_src);
  });
});
```

Without the `('clicked', false)` statement the popup opened by itself.

Greetings!